# Converse to Schur's lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

I would first like to note that this is a homework problem, so any hints in the right direction would be appreciated but no full answers please! The question is as follows:

> Let $R=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{pmatrix}\big\lvert\,a,b,c\in\mathbb{F}\right\}$ be the ring of upper triangular matrices with entries in the field $\mathbb{F}$. Let $M=\mathbb{F}^{2}$ viewed as the $2\times1$ matrices with $R$ acting on the left by matrix multiplication.
> \begin{array}{l}
> \text{(a)}&\text{Show that $M$ is not a simple left $R$-module.} \\
> \text{(b)}&\text{Show that End$_{R}(M)\cong\mathbb{F}$ and hence conclude that the converse} \\
> &\text{to Schur's lemma is false.}
> \end{array}

For part (a) I have that the subgroup $N$ spanned by $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ is a submodule of $M$, and so $M$ cannot be a simple $R$-module. I have considered taking an endomorphism and trying to see what the image of $1$ would be with it. From this I feel like I would perhaps be able to construct an isomorphism $f:\mathbb{F}\rightarrow\textrm{End}_{R}(M)$, but I cannot seem to get my head around this.

Sorry if this is simple, I have missed a few classes recently by way of illness, and I am struggling with the content that I have missed. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: We can't see the full statement of $(b)$.  Of course this is a counterexample for the converse of Schur's theorem. Schur's Lemma says that if $M$ is simple, then $End_R(M)=\Bbb F\cdot id$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde It is moreso the fact that End$_{R}(M)\cong\mathbb{F}$ that I am having trouble with, I cannot see this. Sorry, I should have been more clear in the post.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I can't speak for the OP, but in this case even I can't make use of the tip to "just follow the definition."  For me, it's easy to see $M$ has a unique nontrivial submodule $N$ and $M$ contains no copies of $M/N$, so all nonzero maps are surjections, and they're easily seen to be injections too.  But... how does one connect it to the base field "from the definition of a homomorphism"?

Comment: The best I can do is that "$\phi$ is in particular an $F$ linear transformation of $M$ that commutes with the elements of $R$, and therefore it is central in $R$." but that seems a lot more high-powered than the hint @DietrichBurde

Comment: I should have said “the homomorphism centralizes $R$, and therefore it is in the diagonal copy of $F$”

Comment: @rschwieb I see, yes, this is not just by definition. I suppose this example is not new, but I did not search yet here.

Comment: @DietrichBurde ok, good to know I’m not missing something obvious!

Comment: @rschwieb thanks for the response! Can I clarify that $\phi\in\textrm{End}_{R}(M)$? If so I can see that $\phi$ is $F$ linear and commutes with elements of $R$, but I am not sure how this centralizes $R$, and I do not know what you mean by the diagonal copy of $F$ either

Comment: The diagonal copy of $F$ is $\{\lambda I_2\mid\lambda \in F\}$ where $I_2$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix.

Answer (score 1):

If $\phi\in \mathrm{End}_R(M)$, then there exists a $2\times 2$-matrix $P$ with $\phi(x)=Px$ for all $x\in M$ ($P$ is the standard matrix representation of $\phi$), and $PA=AP$ for every $A\in R$ (since $\phi(Ax)=A\phi(x)$ for every $x\in M$). If we can show $$P=\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&a\end{pmatrix},$$ then the assignment $\phi\mapsto a$ is an isomorphism $\mathrm{End}_R(M)\cong F$.

To see that $P$ is a diagonal matrix, so suppose $P=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$. Let $E_{ij}$ be the $ij$-coordinate matrix. Then, $E_{11},E_{22},E_{12}\in R$. Since $E_{11}P=PE_{11}$, it follows that $b=c=0$. Since
$E_{12}P=PE_{12}$, $a=d$. It now follows that $P=\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&a\end{pmatrix}$ for some $a\in F$ as required.